# How to reload data in section in UICollectionView when using UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` for my collectionView's data source. I have 3 sections in my CollectionView:

```swift
enum Section {
    case section1
    case section2
    case section3
}
```

Initially, I am appending these 3 sections to the collectionView using the following code:

```swift
var snapshot = self.diffableDataSource.snapshot()
snapshot.appendSections([.section1, .section2, .section3])
self.diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot)
```

I then append items to the sections using the following code:

```swift
var snapshot = self.diffableDataSource.snapshot()
snapshot.appendItems([myItems], toSection: .section1)
self.diffableDataSource.apply(snapshot)
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to reload a section in the collection view with a new set of items without appending them to the current ones. The methods available to the `snapshot` only allow for items to be appended to the section, but I need the items of the section to be replaced. I have tried deleting the section, appending it back then appending the new set of items:

```swift
snapshot.deleteSections([.section1])
snapshot.appendSections([.section1])
snapshot.appendItems([myItems], toSection: .section1)
```

This just removes the section but does not load the new items. I am looking for a way to simply refresh the section with the new items, similarly to how you would call `collectionView.reloadData()` when using the normal UICollectionViewDataSource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To modify the snapshot directly

- Determine the items in that section
- Delete the items
- Append the new items
- Reload the section
- Apply the snapshot

This is a generic method as extension of `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`

```
extension UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource {
    
    func replaceItems(_ items : [ItemIdentifierType], in section: SectionIdentifierType) {
        var currentSnapshot = snapshot()
        let itemsOfSection = currentSnapshot.itemIdentifiers(inSection: section)
        currentSnapshot.deleteItems(itemsOfSection)
        currentSnapshot.appendItems(items, toSection: section)
        currentSnapshot.reloadSections([section])
        apply(currentSnapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```

Please name structs representing the data source with starting uppercase letter and in singular form (`MyItem`).